# how to code userform to only enter data in a specific row

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to code a userform that will populate a table that has 13 rows. Each row represents a slot in a machine for a tool, i want the user to select a slot and the form will fill that row with the information or stop the user as there is data in that row already. what i have coded so far is that it will only generate a new row for each entry. Can anyone help me out here please?

Thanks,
Shane.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim addnew As Range
Set wksDMG = Sheet4
Set wksHURCO = Sheet3
Set wksREC1 = Sheet2
Set wksREC2 = Sheet5



'if DMG is selected input data into DMG files  NEED HELP HERE
 If OptionButton1.Value = True Then

 Set addnew = wksDMG.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 addnew.Offset(0, 0).Value = ComboBox7.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox2.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox3.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox4.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox5.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox6.Text


'Data to go to  DMG record log

Set addnew = wksREC1.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
addnew.Offset(0, 0).Value = ComboBox1.Text
addnew.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
addnew.Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox7.Text
addnew.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox2.Text
addnew.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox3.Text
addnew.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox4.Text
addnew.Offset(0, 6).Value = ComboBox5.Text
addnew.Offset(0, 7).Value = ComboBox6.Text
End If

'if Hurco is selected input data into Hurco files  NEED HELP HERE
 If OptionButton2.Value = True Then

 Set addnew = wksHURCO.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 addnew.Offset(0, 0).Value = ComboBox7.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox2.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox3.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox4.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox5.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox6.Text

'Data to go to  HURCO record log

 Set addnew = wksREC2.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 addnew.Offset(0, 0).Value = ComboBox1.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox7.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox2.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox3.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox4.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 6).Value = ComboBox5.Text
 addnew.Offset(0, 7).Value = ComboBox6.Text

 End If


 End Sub
```

Comment: When the cell is selected, will this open the userform to be completed, or do you intend for the userform to already be completed, then the cell is selected (Rather than cmd button) to transfer the data to the worksheet?

Comment: Hi Samuel, i have attached an image above of the user form for reference. the  last line in the user form "Tool Slot" refers to the row the entry will be in i.e 1-13.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution should capture the value of the selected tool slot, then calculate the row number based on the selection. You have not provided enough information to give more details, but here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Private toolSlotRow As Long

Private Sub AddButton_Click()
    If toolSlotRow = -99 Then
        MsgBox "You must select a tool slot before adding your stuff!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim wksDMG As Worksheet
    Set wksDMG = sheet4
    
    Dim tools As Range
    Set tools = wksDMG.Range("A1:Z100")

    '--- check the tool slot row for data
    If IsEmpty(tools.Offset(toolSlotRow, 0)) Then
        '--- empty row, add the tool info
        With tools
            .Offset(0, 0).Value = ComboBox7.Text
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox2.Text
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox3.Text
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox4.Text
            .Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox5.Text
            .Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox6.Text
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "The tool slot selected already has data, do something else!"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ToolSlotComboBox_Change()
    '--- also check here for "no selection" and set an appropriate value
    If ToolSlotComboBox.ListIndex = 0 Then
        '--- this might be the "default - unselected" value
        toolSlotRow = -99
    Else
        toolSlotRow = ToolSlotComboBox.ListIndex
    End If
End Sub
```